# Hide navigation control for better control on flow

Tags: wpf, xaml, navigation

I am using **Page** classes to its **NavigationService.Navigate** API to create navigation between few pages. In the page I have provided buttons for navigation but I am getting following control for free.

[image]

Is there someway to hide this control so that its not shown?

Comment: Is your page hosted inside a Frame?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your page rendered inside of a frame? A frame by default supports Navigation. If this is the case you have to set the navigation visibility property of the frame control to hidden.

```
<Frame Name="Frame1" NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden" >
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `Page` object has `ShowsNavigationUI` property that you can use.

```
<Page ...
      ShowsNavigationUI="False">
    <Grid Background="LightBlue" />
</Page>
```

Comment: With ShowNavigationUI set to false, I still get that control on top